# No authentication manager set. Reauthentication of users when changing passwords will not be performed

Tags: spring, struts2, spring-security, struts

I have a web application running in the following environment.

- Spring Framework 4.0.0 GA
- Spring Security 3.2.0 GA
- Apache Struts 2.3.16

On deployment of the application, the following information appears on the server terminal.

> No authentication manager set. Reauthentication of users when changing
>   passwords will not be performed.

It is however, neither a warning nor an error. The log level is `INFO`.

---

The complete information is as follows.

```
Jan 02, 2014 11:02:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.35\conf\Catalina\localhost\TestStruts.xml
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:03 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:03 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Jan 02 11:03:03 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:03 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:05 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:05 AM org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion performVersionChecks
INFO: You are running with Spring Security Core 3.2.0.RELEASE
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:05 AM org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler <init>
INFO: Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.2.0.RELEASE
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:05 AM org.springframework.security.config.http.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser parseInterceptUrlsForFilterInvocationRequestMap
INFO: Creating access control expression attribute 'hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')' for /admin_side/ **
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:05 AM org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser checkFilterChainOrder
INFO: Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 300, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 700, <org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>, order = 1100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1500, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2000, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2200, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 2300]
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:06 AM org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.method.MapBasedMethodSecurityMetadataSource#0' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.method.MapBasedMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:06 AM org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:06 AM org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean '(inner bean)' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.annotation.SecuredAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:06 AM org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource#0' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:06 AM org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'org.springframework.security.methodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:06 AM org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:07 AM org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean createNativeEntityManagerFactory
INFO: Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'TestStrutsPU'
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:07 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:07 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.7.Final}
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:07 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:07 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:07 AM org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: TestStrutsPU
    ...]
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:08 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider
INFO: HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:08 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:11 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:11 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:14 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/Login],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String spring.controller.LoginController.onSubmit(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:14 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/Login],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String spring.controller.LoginController.showForm(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,java.util.Map) throws java.io.IOException
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:14 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/LoginFailed],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String spring.controller.LoginController.loginError(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap) throws java.io.IOException
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:15 AM org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain <init>
INFO: Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/login.jsp*'], []
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:15 AM org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Validated configuration attributes
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:15 AM org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager initDao



INFO: No authentication manager set. Reauthentication of users when changing passwords will not be performed.



Jan 02, 2014 11:03:16 AM org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain <init>
INFO: Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter@b5f385, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@186d678, org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter@16a6110, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@10a7fe9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@53bd68, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@1b811ae, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@190eaae, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@11f5198, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@125e846, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@1b45682, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@9ba80c, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@135b24b, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@4c7a58]
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:16 AM org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator checkLoginPageIsntProtected
INFO: Checking whether login URL '/admin_login/Login.action' is accessible with your configuration
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:16 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 12609 ms
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (spring) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ActionFactory)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ResultFactory)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ConverterFactory)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.InterceptorFactory)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ValidatorFactory)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.FileManagerFactory)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.CollectionConverter)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.ArrayConverter)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DateConverter)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.NumberConverter)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.StringConverter)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionPropertiesProcessor)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionFileProcessor)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionAnnotationProcessor)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.TypeConverterCreator)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.TypeConverterHolder)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProvider)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.LocaleProvider)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxyFactory)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ObjectTypeDeterminer)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.ActionMapper)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (jakarta) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequest)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.components.UrlRenderer)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ActionValidatorManager)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStackFactory)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionProvider)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionContextFactory)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.PatternMatcher)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StaticContentLoader)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.UnknownHandlerManager)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.views.util.UrlHelper)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParser)
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.config.DefaultBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Loading global messages from [global]
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory info
INFO: Initializing Struts-Spring integration...
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory info
INFO: Setting autowire strategy to name
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:18 AM org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory info
INFO: ... initialized Struts-Spring integration successfully
Jan 02, 2014 11:03:20 AM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase start
INFO: The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TestStruts]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
```

It has not yet caused any problem in the application. It was happening with the earlier versions which I was using. They were,

- Spring Framework 3.2.2
- Spring Security 3.2.0 M1

What does it mean? Am I missing something? Can this be solved somehow?

---

The `spring-security.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http pattern="/Login.jsp*" security="none"></http>

    <http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">

        <session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession">
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
        </session-management>

        <intercept-url pattern="/admin_side/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" requires-channel="any"/>

    <form-login login-page="/admin_login/Login.action" authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccessHandler" authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"/> 
        <logout logout-success-url="/admin_login/Login.action" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
       <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
               users-by-username-query="select email_id, password, enabled from user_table where lower(email_id)=lower(?)"
               authorities-by-username-query="select ut.email_id, ur.authority from user_table ut, user_roles ur where ut.user_id=ur.user_id and lower(ut.email_id)=lower(?)"/>
       </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="loginSuccessHandler" class="loginsuccesshandler.LoginSuccessHandler"/>
    <beans:bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="loginsuccesshandler.AuthenticationFailureHandler" />

    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="false">
        <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* admin.dao.*.*(..))" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    </global-method-security>
</beans:beans>
```

The `web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>AdminLoginNocacheFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>filter.AdminLoginNocacheFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AdminLoginNocacheFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin_login/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>NoCacheFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>filter.NoCacheFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>NoCacheFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin_side/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>struts.devMode</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message occurs because `jdbc-user-service` actually uses an instance of `JdbcUserDetailsManager` internally. This class supports creating and updating users and changing of passwords in addition to just reading a user's details.

If you are using the `changePassword` function then the class will optionally check the old password for you as part of the update, by [calling an injected `AuthenticationManager`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/provisioning/JdbcUserDetailsManager.java#L203).

Since you aren't using this functionality (only the `loadUserByUsername` is needed for authentication) you can safely ignore the message.